# EACCES (PERMISSION DENIED) on read simple file txt

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
         File myFile = new File(PathFileToRead);

            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
```

i used this code to read a file , but probably, with the last system update , i have not permission to do that. can you help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: what error u got show your logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html as per new Marshmallow update in android

Answer (score 0):

add read permission into your manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If your are on Marshmallow you need to use runtime permission request

Answer (score 0):

Checkout in Manifest file if you have added following line -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Additionally also check if you have added Marshmallow's runtime check for permission. For detail, on how to use it, you can check it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160573/842607).

Answer (score 0):

i added in my MainActivity this code below, and i solve it. Thank a lot

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);`

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        /*HERE PERMISSION IS ALLOWED.
        *
        * YOU SHOULD CODE HERE*/


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission deny to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```