# Permission issue on android lollipop device after upgarde

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-5.1.1-lollipop, target-sdk

I have updated my device few days ago. Its an lollipop upgrade, but still it started asking permissions for my app at run time.

I have `targetSDK 21`

But when I open app it pops up for gps permission and if user denied it, it stops working.
I also used `checkSelfPermission` but it is retuning `Granted(0)` every time even user denied it.
My current android version of Phone is android `5.1.1`

Device having android 5.1.1 but its OS is customised by MI like samsung phones. So after upgrade it started asking permission for resource like GPS, Contact and other. Its android sdk version is android 5.1.1 not Android 6.0 which have Runtime Permissions.

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require to implement runtime permission check for Android-21 plus device. Check the solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160573/842607). You will find how array has been utilized in that, mostly that is were user stucks.

Additionally, if denied then you cannot force user to use that functionality. In short you need to bypass that module.

Comment: My android device android 5.1.1. Still it is asking for permission at runtime. The code provide in the link is for Android 6.0 and above.

Comment: then apply check... whether check is required or not at runtime. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {}`

Answer (score 0):

change the sdk version under gradlebuild `minSdkVersion 20 check from here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html`

Answer (score 0):

**Lollipop** have no runtime permission mechanism.

Runtime Premission came up with Android M.