# App crashed while running in marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: android

I have developed android app which it works fine for my samsung note 3 android 5.0 but when I have tried to install it on two devices (Samsung S7 and Sony Z5)with marshmallow 6.0.1 it crashes. Below is the build gradle:

Complete Gradle

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.user.cellularnetworkinfor_v8"
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/opencsv-3.7.jar')
  }
```

**********************************Manifest***************************

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.user.cellularnetworkinfor_v8">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Could you post stack trace?

Comment: add you complete gradle and post what error you get

Comment: you should look into the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

That might be because of some dangerous permission , You have to specify runtime permission from android 6.0 , some example of dangerous permissions are Access_fine_location,read and writememory etc,

To confirm it please post your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of feature of Android M [How to ask permission runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) alternatively for checking permission issue you can specify manually from
`settings -> Apps -> Configure Apps` in android M Device.

Also refer this post [Marshallow changing permissions at run time crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160465/marsmallow-changing-permissions-at-run-time-crashes-app)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take **RunTimePermission**
See This how to take Permission runtime https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/4741746