# Permission Request (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, permissions

Android 6

I wrote the next code that checks for permissions and if there are no such permissions, it asks a user to give them.

```
private void checkDiskPermission ()
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "no disk access" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "disk access - OK" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "no GPS access" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS access - OK" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This code works fine for GPS permissions, but not for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. A dialog appears in only one case.

Why can it be so?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/37160573/842607

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are requesting it for 2 times simultaneously.
That's why it is taking last request.

The solution is that you have to ask both permission in one request

Like this-

```
private void checkDiskPermission ()
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Permissions" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Has Permissions" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `permission > 1`, than it has to combined together at Runtime.

According to Google, beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it’s missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.

Things to keep in mind while asking Multiple Permission:

1. Number of Permission.
2. Never Ask Again Checkox

[Look at the Source for Multiple Permission Request](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But Vishal Chhodwani was the first.

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine. No issue in java code for run time permission. Once check your manifest have you add that line or not?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: yes, I added it. I've found out that I had several simultaneous permission requests. Splitting them has solved the issue. I ask for permissions only when a user wants to use GPS functions in the program or when he/she wants to use functions that write data to the disk.