# Sharing Failed in Intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am trying to send image using intent as below :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(mArray[position]));
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

EDIT: FILE IMAGE ARRAY

```
private void createDrawbleArray(File fileDir) {

    mArray = new File[Constants.TOTAL_GRID_ICONS];
    TypedArray tArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array._images);

    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.TOTAL_GRID_ICONS; i++) {
        mArray[i] = getFileForResource(this, tArray.getResourceId(i, -1), fileDir, "a" + i + ".png");
    }
    tArray.recycle();

}
```

EDIT : PERMISSIONS

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

But, unfortunately its giving me Sharing failed toast.
What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share your image file location?

Comment: its array i have created as ... editing...

Comment: /data/user/0/com.example.android.supportv13.sampleime/files/images/a2.png

Comment: can u show how are u retreiving the uri from intent??

Comment: Also Permissions list from Manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: I hope you also have provided Runtime permissions for Marshmallow+ devices. Reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/37160573/842607

Comment: checking in lolipop sir...

Comment: What is the output you getting for `Uri.fromFile(mArray[position])`

Comment: I can share "text" successfully. But, issue is with image.

Comment: Do one thing. Try to display image in `ImageView` from `Uri.fromFile(mArray[position])`. If you can display image then URI you getting is correct then we will see some other options. If not then URI you getting is not correct.

Comment: @JimitPatel file:///data/user/0/com.example.android.supportv13.sampleime/files/images/a2.png (LOG of uri)

Comment: @JimitPatel could not set on ImageView.

Comment: Hello Sir, I got the solution and posted answer. You can check. But Now I want to share that image to opened activity. I do not want the Intent Chooser, image should be share to opened current app. How ? Any idea sir ?

Comment: What is your targetSdk in build.gradle?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: could not set on `ImageView` means problem with URI.

Comment: Yes sir, earlier i was taking uri as Uri.fromFile(mArray[position]). But, the solution is Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.strFileProviderPackage), mArray_Icons[position]);

Comment: I have used contentProvider to do so.

Comment: Hello Sir, Still a little issue, When I am sharing image to Facebook Messenger, it gives me error below sent images(actually not sent).. that is Send failed. Tap to retry or delete.  I have added  shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); to my intent. no success.

Comment: log: Writing exception to parcel
                                                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri content://com.mayar.inputcontent/my_images/a1.png from pid=17497, uid=10151 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: Hey, one more little issue, Image share with WhatsApp goes with Black background since i am using Transperent png images. i want that it go with white background. Any idea ?

Comment: [Working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619468/6667510) tested on Lollipop, Marshmallow, Oreo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your image file location is within your project you can't share image with external app.

Here are few ways to share

1. create your file provider
2. store your image file in external directory.

check these links to create your file provider

1. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html
3. http://www.blogc.at/2014/03/23/share-private-files-with-other-apps-fileprovider/

Comment: I am using InputMethodService of CommitContent API.

Comment: I can share "text" successfully. But, issue is with image.

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for your valuable answer. 
B

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for your valuable answer. 
But, I could not share the image with the Facebook Messenger. 
Why ? Any Idea ?

Comment: One more thing, I am creating virtual keyboard app, my keyboard opens in another messeging app. Now, if that apps does not have support for Commit content API, it will be share via Intent. I am checking that particular app is supporting Commit content API or not. Condition comes true in case of Facebook Messenger. Now, I want to do it with ShareIntent in case of Facebook Messenger.. So, How can i check that Facebook Messenger is currently runing. NOTE : I am using InputMethodService.

Comment: Hey, one more little issue, Image share with WhatsApp goes with Black background since i am using Transperent png images. i want that it go with white background. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

finally, i got the solution :

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType(getResources().getString(R.string.strIntentType));
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.strFileProviderPackage), mArrayIcons[position]);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Used FileProvider to do so and it works like a charm..!!! yeppii.

Comment: Hey, one more little issue, Image share with WhatsApp goes with Black background since i am using Transperent png images. i want that it go with white background. Any idea ?