# Security Exception got while sending image in Facebook Messenger via INTENT share

Tags: android, image, facebook, android-intent

I am developing app in which i am sharing image using intent with the use of FILEPROVIDER declared in Manifest.

I got success in sharing particular image on WhatApp, Hangout, Textra etc.. but unfortunately not success with FACEBOOK MESSENGER.

LOGCAT:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri content://com.mayar.inputcontent/my_images/a1.png from pid=8677, uid=10151 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:615)
                                                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
                                                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:471)
                                                                                               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:416)
                                                                                               at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:313)
                                                                                               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I am getting "Send failed. Tap to retry or delete." with red color below image in Facebook messenger.

What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: This is my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197545/sharing-failed-in-intent

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24467912/1939564

Comment: or try this `getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(getCallingPackage(), 
          contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

Comment: Sir, Will you pls. elaborate the method getCallingPackage() pls.

Comment: can not resolve method getCallingPackage‌​();

Comment: Sorry for late reply. `getCallingPackage()` is a method of `Activity` class so you either call it inside your Activity or need to use instance of your activity to call it. You can also cast your context like this `(Activity (context)).getCallingPackage()`

Comment: am using Service(InputMethodService) and created layout dynamically inside onCreateInputView() method.