# react native app made to restart when permission settings are changed

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a react native app, which is working fine on both Android and iOS. Upon changing any permissions (Camera, Storage) through the Settings option, the app should get restarted.

For example, if I am on the home screen and I changed the permissions, the app will get restarted and takes me back to the login screen.

Are there any options to maintain the current app state (both Android and iOS)?

Please suggest.

Comment: Nope, app restarts when permission is changed outside of it (since it would potentially crash when thinking it has permission for things)

Comment: Thanks @MotiAzu, The native android/ios apps(Whatsapp,..) are not getting restarted.

Comment: Oh, wrong assumption on my part then.

Comment: Although these suggest otherwise - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488589/android-marshmallow-dynamic-permission-change-kills-all-application-processes

Comment: Dear @Pandiarajan, I couldn't understand exactly, You want to restart your app or it is restarting and you don't want it?

Answer (score 1):

I think for android you need to create background service which fetch from android device about **device status** but for ios if app runs then from **app delegate** you can get status from there

btw appstate libary ofr React Native is reactnative.dev/docs/appstate